# Self Contained WPF .net

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio

I am working on a proof of concept for a client who wants a Windows 7 or higher app (.net WPF) to be self contained on a USB drive with no install. Basically service tech with go in plug drive in run app.

Is this possible? Any one give me any hints?

Steve

Comment: Are you presuming a specific version of the .NET framework is installed on the target computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the .exe easily enough, and include any external dependencies (.dlls) in the same folder on the USB stick. The .NET framework is included with Windows 7, so as long as you allow for the lowest version possible (3.5.1), it should be possible to then 'plug and play'. You'll have to give specific issues if you want a more specific answer.

As is mentioned in the comments, if you want a newer version of the .NET framework you'll have to physically install it on the client machine; or at least have a check in the .exe that looks to see if the version is valid, and informs the user if it is not.

Comment: Actually, Windows 7 includes .NET Framework version 3.5.1, not 4.

Comment: OK That sounds easy enough thanks. Now what if I wanted to include a newer version of the .net FW can it co-exist if it is already installed if I include it as an external dependency?

Comment: Different versions of .NET get along with each other just fine, BUT you will have to actually install the newer framework, which will probably require admin privileges and a reboot.